# c# thread declaration

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, declaration

I see the following declarations:

```
ThreadStart myThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(Work.DoWork);
Thread myThread = new Thread(myThreadDelegate);
myThread.Start();
```

Can they be simplified as the following?

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work.DoWork));
myThread.Start();
```

If yes, what is the second method called?  what are the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: and what do you call that newer declaration method?  =/

Comment: you are doing the same thing in both. Its called Instatiating a thread object.  In the first example you declare the variables and assign them new objects.  You then pass these to the thread. You do the exact same thing in the second example without declaring them in a variable.  The only real need to declare the variable is if you need to access the thread outside of the method that called it.

Comment: 'post-optimization refactored code'? 'That neat one-liner'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can even be simplified to:

```
var myThread = new Thread(Work.DoWork);
myThread.Start();
```

There's not much of a difference. In your first example, the delegate instance gets a name, `myThreadDelegate`, that could in theory be used later (maybe for something else) in the method.

It's mostly a matter of taste if one prefers one long expression with many levels in it, or many little expressions with temporaray variables that are then combined.

In any case, it is simpler, in my opinion, to use implicit conversion from method group, as in just `Work.DoWork`, than to write `new ThreadStart(Work.DoWork)`. See the sentence *C# 2.0 provides a simpler way to write the previous declaration* in [How to: Declare, Instantiate, and Use a Delegate (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176.aspx). This simpler way is formally called a *method group conversion*.

For information on the `var` keyword, see [Implicitly Typed Local Variables (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).

Of course the ultimate one-liner in your example will be:

```
(new Thread(Work.DoWork)).Start();
```

in which case you don't even get a reference to (variable for) your new thread (the instance method `Start()` returns `void`).

Comment: OK, that 'var' is called an implicit declaration, I believe.

Comment: @hoangnguyen The `var` is called an implicitly typed (local) variable. Since the type of the right-hand side of the assignment operator `=` has type `Thread`, the `var` simply means `Thread`. It's still a strongly typed variable of type `Thread`. I updated my answer a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  It isn't called anything, there are no pros or cons.  You can use additional C# syntax sugar with:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(Work.DoWork);
myThread.Start();
```

And it will automatically infer that you want to create a ThreadStart delegate object.

Comment: uhm...  I think the second method in the question is called anonymous method.  correct me if I am wrong on that.

Comment: No, an anonymous method uses the *delegate* keyword.  It isn't called anything meaningful beyond "not using a local variable".  You don't need local variables to pass a method argument.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly could be simplified to the second method. However, if the other objects were needed during debugging they would not be available. It's unlikely they would, but it's worth noting that building more concise lines always have that drawback.

Comment: I gotta agree.  I never want to find myself unable to see the tiny details needed for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can.

If the delegate is used only to be passed as a reference to the new Thread() method, then that sequence may be optimized that way - one less object declaration.

Comment: the object is actually created in both cases, it's just given a name in the first one and is anonymous in the second.  The only "optimization" is that for the first the object can't be GCed until after it leaves scope, for the second it leaves scope right after it's used, but even the compiler is likely to optimized that for you and allow it to be collected earlier, and if not, it's not a significant loss.

Comment: I know, and you're right @Servy - i meant 'optimization' as in human readability.

Answer (score 1):

Both are same.

In first example you have `myThreadDelegate` but it has no other usage other than getting passed to [Thread constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

OK,
someone suggested this but then deleted his/her answer:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread ( () => Work.Dowork() );
```

that thing is called a lambda expression.

Comment: But this is not same as OP examples. It adds another method call int between

Comment: You must have `new Thread ( () => Work.Dowork() )` for this to work. Note the `()` for method call after `DoWork`. The lambda expression is one kind of an anonymous function. It will create a method for you that behaves like the arrow, and use that generated method to create the delegate instance.

Comment: @Tilak Great, I hadn't seen that. The deleted comment also forgot the `()`. Maybe the comment was deleted because its author realized that there's no need for a lambda when the named method (`DoWork`) already has the required signature and return type.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen:  I am new to Threading, so what is the required signature and return type?

Comment: @hoangnguyen If you look at [the `ThreadStart` delegate type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx) you see that it has zero parameters (i.e. takes zero arguments). That's because there's nothing in the parentheses after the word `ThreadStart`. The **signature** of a method or delegate consists of the parameter list (order and type of parameters). Other stuff like `ref` or `out` modifiers on parameters, or `params` or optional parameters can also be a part of the signature. The **return type** is `void` here.

Comment: For a method to "match" a delegate, the signature and return type must be correct. If they are not, sometimes you can fix this with an anonymous function, like a lambda. For example: `() => DoWorkOnObjAndReturnValue(someObjToUse)`